# WCF database login always fails

Tags: database, wcf, authentication

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit.

I made a mistake of opening a VS2008 .net 3.5 wcf application in VS2010 and building it and then following the upgrade prompts.

Since then, any database access from my wcf web site results in a login failure. If I choose file as the web site, then my own login is rejected by the sql server. If I publish to http, no identity is assigned to my application pool (ASP.NET v4.0) can login even though I add it as a user to the database.

This is driving me nuts. When I was working with .net 3.5 and VS2008, it worked fine. I had to add the login for the identity of the application pool (DefaultAppPool) after I published to http, but then it worked fine.

If I write a simple win forms application and use `select my database` using the Data Source Configuration Wizard, I have access to my database. It's not my database login credentials, but something else that WCF requires.

Can anyone shed some light on this?
Otherwise I might need a new screen.

PS I ran these to try and fix things, but it resolved nothing.

```
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis" -i -enable
"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer (at least I think I did).

With VS2008 .net 3.5 when I use a wcf class library in my web site I had to very little to the web.config.
I had to make a few adjustments so that it would use my class library and not the service and code behind class it adds by default.

This time I had to copy and paste the ConnectionStrings element from my wcf class library app.config file.
I did not have to do this before (I double checked another example).

The web.config file appears to much smaller when built using VS2010 .NET 4.0 than with VS2008 .NET 3.5.
It looks like one has to migrate more stuff across than before.